# Wordpress - Add tags as classes? (post_class)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags, taxonomy

I'm surprised I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere online, but is there any way to add the tags of a post to the classes?

I am trying to add a filter to post_class, but it isn't working:

```
function tag_to_class($classes) {
        global $post;
        foreach((get_the_tags($post->ID)) as $tag)
            $tags[] = $tag->name;
            return $tags;
    }
    add_filter('post_class', 'tag_to_class');
    add_filter('body_class', 'tag_to_class');
```

I get the error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Any help greatly appreciated,
Thank you!

Comment: actually tags are already added to post_class

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_tags` has to be used in The Loop, but if you're already in The Loop you can use `the_tags` to get a list of tags on the current post like so:

```
   <div class="<?php the_tags("", " ", "");?>">
```

I don't have a wordpress to play with right now, but I think you can add them to `post_class`
like this:

```
<div class="<?php post_class(the_tags("", " ", "")); ?>">
```

Comment: Ah. What if I want to use post_class function though so that it also adds the taxonomy and status classes?

Comment: I had this problem before, but I can't remember exactly how I solved it. I don't have a WP to play with right now. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
function tags_to_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    $posttags = get_the_tags( $post->ID );

    if ( $posttags ){
        foreach( $posttags as $tag )
            $tags[] = $tag->slug;
        return $tags;
}
add_filter('body_class', 'tags_to_body_class');
```